# MarkLogic generic language support

Tags: indexing, marklogic, stemming

As per the documentation:
The generic language support only stems words to themselves, queries in these languages will not include variations of words based on their meanings in the results.

```
xdmp:document-insert("/lang/test.xml", <el xml:lang="fr">chats</el>)
```

Considering I do not have a license for french language, will the word 
"chats" be stemmed to "chat" in the term list ? or will it be indexed as chats, i.e. without any variations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check this yourself using [`cts:stem`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:stem):

```
cts:stem("chats", "fr")
```

Without necessary licenses it simply returns `chats`.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

No license for French means no stemming for French.

I'm actually kind of confused by the question.  If it did work without the license, then what would the license get you?

Comment: Hi. There was some confusion as some of my colleagues we're interpreting "stemmed to itself" as stemmed to the specified language. Thanks for clarifying it out.

Comment: Ah, I think that's a fancy way to say that stemmed searches will run but just like they're unstemmed.